# if variable exist execute else skip in js

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, variables, charts

I am using google charts. This is my code for bar graph:

```
function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([

        ['Task', 'Weak Area'],
        ['web', 3],

        [('<?php echo $type[0]; ?>'), 5],
        [('<?php echo $type[1]; ?>'), 4],
        [('<?php echo $type[2]; ?>'), 4],
        [('<?php echo $type[3]; ?>'), 4],
    ]);

    // Optional; add a title and set the width and height of the chart
    var options = {
        'title': 'Weak Areas',
        'width': 550,
        'height': 400,
        animation: {
            duration: 1000,
            easing: 'out',
            startup: true
        }
    };
}
```

Here the main concern is plave where i am passing php variable. Actually i am getting thi variable from other page. and if suppose $type[0] exist its output will be shown to chart similarly for others, but if a variable for example $type[2] is not present the chart does not appear.

What I wanted to do, suppose `$type[2]` does not exist its output should not be shown but the graph should be shown without it.

something as this:

```
 [('<?php echo $type[0]; ?>'), 5], [('<?php echo $type[1]; ?>'), 4], [('<?php if($type[2] is present){ echo $type[2]} else {blank} ?>'), 4]
```

and similarly for other such as `$type[3]`,`$type[4]` and so on...

Please help me for the same.

Comment: Try `if(isset($type[2])){ echo $type[2]}`  isset() is used to check if a variable or array/object element exists before using it

Comment: but the 4 value which is infront of this this statement is being shown, how to remove that too

Comment: Wrap it in another if isset condition.